# How to implement Cora Data Persistent Management

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, persistentmanager

I have the following structure so far:
- Singleton NetworkingManager (login, logout API calls)
- Subclass NSManagedObject (with son extension)

I don't know how to structure this part of the app?
Do I need a PersistentManager/global ObjectManagedContext?

Here are my classes:

NetworkingManager (API-call)

```
func getContacts() { 

        GET(APIURL.URL_CONTACTS ,parameters: nil,
        { (operation : NSURLSessionDataTask!, response : AnyObject!) -> Void in
            var contacts = [Contacts]()
            contacts <<<<* response
            //_sharedPersistentManager.save(contacts!)
        }, { (operation : NSURLSessionDataTask!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
           println("Error contacts")
    })
}
```

Model

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Contacts: NSManagedObject, Deserializable {

@NSManaged var firstname: String
@NSManaged var lastname: String
@NSManaged var id: String

required init(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let managedContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
        as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Contacts", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)!
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    self.id <<< data["id"]
    self.firstname <<< data["1"]
    self.lastname <<< data["2"]
}
}
```

This code fails... (Bad_ACCESS)

I struggle with the basic class design.
Would be so kind of you to post some pseudo-code and I can understand the basic concept.

All Tutorials explain how to save or fetch some data, but not a real concept for a whole app...

I'm looking for a basic concept like: 
- You should implement one Persistent Manager Singleton class

//PersistentManager 
- global ObjectManagedContext 
- Singleton 
- func save (model1: Model1) 
- func save (model2: Model2) 
- ....

//NetworkingManager 
- Singleton 
- ...

EDIT: 
- added some code 
- added further explanation

Comment: You've got so much nonstandard stuff in that code that it's impossible to tell where your problem might be. What is `<<<`? Or `<<<<*`? These aren't standard Swift operators. And what is that `GET(...)` call? You're using so much custom stuff that it's hard to tell what's really going on.

Comment: <<<  and <<<<* are both custom operators of the JSON deserializer extension. They deserialize the array from the server.
https://github.com/isair/JSONHelper

GET is an API-call. I have forgotten to post the function header..

I think the problem is my entire structure. Small code issues are easy to solve later.

Comment: Whats with the class Contacts (plural) ?  I assume this class might represent a single Contact (person), in which case rather use the singular name Contact for the class name.  Also not sure you want to be creating and inserting the object into the MOC from inside the objects init() method.

Comment: Yes you're right I will rename it to Contact. I have to implement the init method because of the Json parsing protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Typically your App would have one database (but it may have more than one, depending on your requirements).  If we assume you only need one then you need to create a Core Data database (persistent store) and at a minimum one NSPersistentStoreCoordinator and one ManagedObjectContext in order to create and update database records via the ManagedObjects.  Just use the template app to get sample code for doing this.

I would not try using the ManagedObjects init() method for creating the object, instead use a helper function in another class to do this.  This init() method will get called automatically when you create the object so you might use it to set some default values for properties.

Below is an example ManagedObject (Swift class) and an Objective-C helper function.  Apologies in advance, you will need to convert this to the equivalent Swift code.

```
//
//  DocumentCategory.swift
//  Sample
//

import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(DocumentCategoryX)
class DocumentCategoryX: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var image: NSData
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var sortIndex: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var viewName: String
    @NSManaged var documents: NSSet

}
```

Sample helper function to create a managed object (a Core Data database record)

```
- (NSManagedObject*)createNewCategory:(NSString*)entityName sortIndex:(int)sortIndex withName:(NSString *)name viewName:(NSString *)viewName icon:(UIImage*)icon;
{
    NSManagedObject *newCat = [NSEntityDescription
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName
                               inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [newCat setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sortIndex] forKey:@"sortIndex"];
    [newCat setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
    [newCat setValue:viewName forKey:@"viewName"];

    [newCat setValue:UIImagePNGRepresentation(icon) forKey:@"image"];  // iOS
    return newCat;
}
```

Swift function to save the MOC.  Call this whenever you need to make sure things are written to disk.

```
// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
            var error: NSError? = nil
            if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {

                //FLOG("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
                // Probably need a message to the user warning that a save failed!
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you extend your sample code for saving objects and parsing Json to NsManagedObjects?

Comment: I don't have any Json code but remember that you can't just parse a Json object to a NSManagedObject subclass directly, at best you would have to parse it into some pure Swift or Obj-C class and then copy the attributes to the NSManagedObject created using the method above.

Comment: Do I really need two Objects for such a simple task?